# Date range search in jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have on column of listed date,i want to search a range of date(FromDate,ToDate)..
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oTable = $('#listings_row').dataTable();
var asInitVals = new Array();
        $("thead input").keyup( function () {
                oTable.fnFilter( this.value,  parseInt($(this).attr('id')) );
            } );
   $("#dateaddedSto").datepicker();
$("#dateaddedS").datepicker();
});
```

here is simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n4UKd/1/

Comment: Try using this: http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: not helpful for my requirements